# Bulk Insert in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

This is my SQL query for bulk insert

```
BULK
INSERT userTable
FROM 'c:\name\userTable.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

It results in the following error

> sql Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\name\userTable.txt"
>   could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot
>   find the path specified.)

Comment: Due to error message, please check your file path and file name.

Comment: Is that SQL Server instance on your local machine?? If not: is that file on that remote server's C:\ drive?? You cannot reach from a remote SQL Server machine onto your local machine's C:\ drive and go grab a file.....

Comment: -1. Because the error message is OBVIOUS (File not found) and you dont do anything to txplain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your setup? TWO possibilities:

- The server has no permission to that folder. The server iwll come iwth it's own credentials, not yours.
- The server is ona another machine.

Bulk insert is not a network transfer, it i a command to the server to load a file, which then is executed FROM the server process ON the server machine WITH the credentials the server process runs on.

So, can the server, with the server user, read this parth on the server and find the file?

Obvious answer: NO. Pleae check and invest more than 10 seconds thinking about the problem - the error message hier is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename differs (Code: userTable.txt, Error: newUser.txt). Are you sure either? file exists and is readable?